# How to use Maven + Karaf? I'm stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-karaf

How to create and publish a simple hello world application on localhost with Karaf and Maven? There is no working resources about this question on the web right now. I spent hours researching.

I keep going back to this tutorial but I cannot progress as versions of karaf, maven, eclipse are changed. I'm trying to figure out by trial error which is not helping. http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/02/15/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+1+-+Installation+and+First+application

The whole work: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1633708/efdba72fed8c841fa94dd087c6cb8f69

I am able to follow these guides and deploy an existing application (/karaf-doc) working on localhost:8181:

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_deploy_a_sample_application

https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/webcontainer

Comment: Do you expect an answer to the "How to..." or a/some link(s)?

Comment: Anything really

Comment: I just went through the tutorial with a current karaf 3.0.8 version. It worked all fine for me. The example compiled and deployed. What exactly happened when you tried it? Anyway I will update the example to the current karaf 4.x version but there should be not many changes required.

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated the [Karaf Tutorial Part 1](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/DIBZ) to the lastest karaf version. I also switched it to the annotation based model of creating blueprint contexts. So no more of the dreaded hand written xml. Please try the new one and give some feedback if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit skeptical about your 10 hour research.

There is plenty of documentation and blogs showing how to install Camel inside Karaf. In fact I wrote about it on my own blog a while back. Installing Camel in Karaf is the easy part. You can do that in 1 min.

Designing generic and stable Camel integrations is the hard part. Coming up with a effective build&deploy process is also tricky.

What is your hello world application about?

You can simply do a file transfer which is about as simple as it gets.

```
from("file://C:/test?fileName=input.txt").to("file://C:/out?fileName=output.txt");
```

Just build the bundle and in the simplest form place it in the deploy folder in Karaf and it will be automatically installed.

Run `bundle:list` to see that the bundle has been set in the active mode.